# During authentication ".FindByNameAsync()" always returns "NULL"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm writing a project with asp.net core mvc 2.2, my problem is:
During authentication ".FindByNameAsync()" always returns "NULL" and therefore authentication process is not successful.
My LOGIN form contains:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">

    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="Danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <input asp-for="Mobile" type="text" class="form-control" style="direction:ltr;">
            <span asp-validation-for="Mobile" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>                        
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" style="direction:ltr;">
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>                        
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" style="text-align: center;" value="LOG IN" />
        </div>
    </div>



</form>
```

And my AccountController.cs contains:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Register register)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(register.Mobile);

    if(user!=null)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, register.Password, false, false);

        if(result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Account");
        }
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "User name/password not found");
    return View();

}
```

And my database table is:

```
public class Register
{

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdFK")]
    public ICollection<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }


    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Family { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Mail { get; set; }

}
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

I also used "register.Name" but it did not work!!!
The values were in DB too. I tried with `.FindByEmailAsync(register.Mail)` too but it did not work.
I used breakpoint on begin of "AccountController.cs" and I saw "register.Mobile" value was "CORRECT" but unfortunately "user" value still was "NULL"!!!
I also created a new project and implemented previous project into it, but it didn't work too.
Please note that I have Windows 10 and VisualStudio 2017 15.9.5 and VisualStudio 2019 preview 1.1 installed on my computer.

Comment: Please don't use caps like this.

Comment: Have you tried `_userManager.FindByNameAsync(register.Name)`, using the `Name` instead of `Mobile`?

Comment: I also used register.Name but it did not work!!!

Comment: Are you _sure_ the values are in the db?

Comment: The values are in DB too. I tried with .FindByEmailAsync(register.Mail) too but it did not work.

Comment: Have you set breakpoints so you can step through the code, make sure the values are correctly populated etc?  Is this a new app you are creating or something which already exists?  With new apps these things sometimes use an internal memory by default so if you start and stop the app the memory gets wiped and the values are not there anymore.

Comment: I used breakpoint on begin of "AccountController.cs" and I saw "register.Mobile" value was "CORRECT" but unfortunately user value was "NULL"!!! I think that there is a problem when data are sent from "form".

Comment: If you set the breakpoint and can see that the `register` object is populated then it is not a form problem.  It feels like it is the link between the `UserManagement` service and the db.

Comment: I also created a new project and implemented previous project into it, but it didn't work.
Please note that I have Windows 10 and VisualStudio 2017 15.9.5 and VisualStudio 2019 preview 1.1 installed on my computer.